# Passing scala `Comparable` array to java generic method

Tags: java, scala, generics, comparable

I have these classes in the library:

```
// This is java
public abstract class Property<T extends Comparable<T>> {
     public static Property<T> create(String str) { /* Some code */ }
}
public class PropertyInt extends Property<Integer> {
     public static PropertyInt create(String str) { /* Some code */ }
}
public class PropertyDouble extends Property<Double> {
     public static PropertyDouble create(String str) { /* Some code */ }
}
```

and there is a method that takes a list of `Property`s that I want to use:

```
public void state(Property... properties) {
    /* some code */
}
```

I cannot change the above since they are from a library.
In scala, I have the following code which attempts to pass an array to `void state(Property...)`:

```
// This is scala
val propertyInt = PropertyInt.create("index")
val propertyDouble = PropertyDouble.create("coeff")
state(Array[Property](proeprtyInt, propertyDouble)))
```

The last line of code has an error: `Type mismatch, expected Property[_ <: Comparable[T]], actual Array[Property]` How do I fix this?

Note: This is a simplified version of some more complicated code. In the real code, `Property<T extends Comparable<T>>` implements the interface `IProperty<T extends Comparable<T>>` and `IProperty` is taken as the arguments for `state`.

Edit: The following

```
 val properties = Array(propertyInt.asInstanceOf[IProperty[_ <: Comparable[_]]],
                  propertyDouble.asInstanceOf[IProperty[_ <: Comparable[_]]])
 state(properties)
```

Gives the error

```
Error:(54, 33) type mismatch;
found   : Array[Property[_ >: _$3 with _$1 <: Comparable[_]]] where type _$1 <: Comparable[_], type _$3 <: Comparable[_]
required: Property[?0] forSome { type ?0 <: Comparable[?0] }
    state(properties)
          ^
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to change the `state` arguments to be generic:

```
public static void state(Property<?> ... properties) {
  /* some code */
}
```

Then you can do:

```
// This is scala
val propertyInt = PropertyInt.create("index")
val propertyDouble = PropertyDouble.create("coeff")

state(propertyInt, propertyDouble)

state(Array(propertyInt, propertyDouble):_*)
```

**Upd** if you can't change the signature of `state`, you can still call it like this:

```
state(Array[Property[_]](propertyInt, propertyDouble):_*)
```

Comment: I cannot change the code for `state`. It is from a library.

Comment: @HenryW., can you create helper method in your java code that takes `Property<?>...` and returns `Property[]`?

Comment: The update does not work. The compiler says a type of `IProperty[?0] for some {type ?0 <: Comparable[?0]}` is expected. Maybe I will try a helper method.

Comment: Change `Array[Property[_]]` to `Array[Property[_ <: Comparable[T]]]`.